# My Sorting.js works fine in firefox but not in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

```
function ts_getInnerText(el) {
if (typeof el == "string") return el;
if (typeof el == "undefined") { return el };
if (el.innerText) return el.innerText;  // Not needed but it is faster
var str = "";

var cs = el.childNodes;
var l = cs.length;
for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    switch (cs[i].nodeType) {
        case 1: // ELEMENT_NODE
            str += ts_getInnerText(cs[i]);
            break;
        case 3: // TEXT_NODE
            str += cs[i].nodeValue;
            break;
    }
}
return str;
```

}

Now when i call this function in IE, it always gets undefined value which raise a error on consol so i added a check for undefined.

```
function ts_sort_caseinsensitive(a, b) {
if (a.cells.length == b.cells.length) {
    if (!(typeof ts_getInnerText(a.cells[SORT_COLUMN_INDEX]) == 'undefined')) {
        aa = ts_getInnerText(a.cells[SORT_COLUMN_INDEX]).toLowerCase();
        bb = ts_getInnerText(b.cells[SORT_COLUMN_INDEX]).toLowerCase();
        if (aa == bb) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (aa < bb) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 1;

    }
}
```

}

after that the columns are starts sorted on click but not properly.. such as i have to click twice to sort it for asc or desc order.